# Step() function in Windows Media Player

Tags: delphi, windows-media-player

I'm using the ActiveX Windows Media Player in Delphi XE3. 
Is it possible to single step through the frames in a video, one at a time? 
According to the MS documentation there is a Step() function: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/controls-step 
But that function doesn't seem to exist in the Delphi IDE. 
When I type in my media control:  WMPlayer1.
The IDE presents a list of possible members, but Step() is no where in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

In the generated WMPLib_TLB.pas file WMPlayer1.controls is declared as an IWMPControls interface. The Step method is however not in IWMPControls but in IWMPControls2. Just doing a typecast works:

```
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      IWMPC2:IWMPControls2;
    begin          
      //WMPlayer1.controls.pause; (Pause first)
      IWMPC2 := IWMPControls2(WMPlayer1.controls);
      IWMPC2.step(1);
    end;
```